# Permutation of string with repeated characters(visited array concept)

Tags: c++, string, math, permutation

```
void per(int count){

    if(count==l){
       printf("%s\n", p);
       return;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
          if(visit[i]==0 ){
          visit[i]=1;
          p[count]=arr[i];
          per(count+1);
          visit[i]=0;   //backtrack
          }
    }
}
```

Above mentioned code is generating for string "aab", the following permutation.

```
aab
aba
aab
aba
baa
baa
```

Some permuted string are repeated? How can I reduce it?
Link to my [code](http://ideone.com/ab4p17).

Comment: Instead of printing each permutation, you could store them in a list and remove duplicates at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You are using C++, so [std:next_permutation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/) is your best friend.

If you want to implement permutations from scratch, use [algorithm description for the next lexicographic permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order). Note that algorithm works well with repeated elements.

```
Find the largest index k such that a[k] < a[k + 1]. If no such index exists, 
   the permutation is the last permutation.

Find the largest index l greater than k such that a[k] < a[l].

Swap the value of a[k] with that of a[l].

Reverse the sequence from a[k + 1] up to and including the final element a[n].
```

Arbitrary c++ [implementation](https://www.nayuki.io/res/next-lexicographical-permutation-algorithm/nextperm.cpp)